# Database compatibility between monero-wallet-gui and cli

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, monero-wallet-cli, lmdb

Is it possible to use the database generated after running monero-wallet-gui with monero-wallet-cli?

If I want to use the monero-wallet-cli I need to run monerod first (not needed with monero-wallet-gui), but if I run the command "./monerod --data-dir /path/to/lmdb-generated-by-monero-wallet-gui" I get the following error:

> ```
> W Found existing LMDB files in /path/to/lmdb-generated-by-monero-wallet-gui
> W Move data.mdb and/or lock.mdb to /path/to/lmdb-generated-by-monero-wallet-gui/lmdb, or delete them, and then restart
> E Error opening database: Database could not be opened
> ```

Because of the small file size of data.mdb after full sync with monero-wallet-gui, I figure this database only contains info of the relevant blocks containing transactions on wich my wallet is involved. Is this the cause of the issue?

Answer (score 0):

> Database compatibility between monero-wallet-gui and cli

They use the same database, i.e. a fully synchronized blockchain that is accessed via a running daemon (monerod).

> Is it possible to use the database generated after running monero-wallet-gui with monero-wallet-cli?

Yes.

> If I want to use the monero-wallet-cli I need to run monerod first (not needed with monero-wallet-gui)

Because the GUI launches a daemon (monerod) behind the scenes. Both wallets (GUI / CLI) need access to a daemon and blockchain.

> but if I run the command "./monerod --data-dir /path/to/lmdb-generated-by-monero-wallet-gui" I get the following error...

The path specified with `--data-dir` needs to be the folder *containing* the lmdb directory, and you can't run *two* instances of `monerod` at the same time using the same database.

> Because of the small file size of data.mdb after full sync with monero-wallet-gui...

If data.mdb is small you have not fully synchronized the database at that path.